# javac *.java Windows command line error : * as illegal chacter

Tags: java, javac

So i tried to compile my java project (9 classes 3 files), and feeling no need for complicated work i tried the standard 'javac *.java' from the folder above the root of project. (and alter from the root itself). Javac throws and parsing error on command line claiming Illegal char < * > at index 0: *.java. options chosen don't seem to matter since 1) i tried a few, 2) it crashes on parsing line of file.

While i do know a work around by just writing down all file paths to all of my .java files, i find this annoying, and potentially problematic in the future. Also i found nothing on the issue what so ever so it may either something very weird or very stupid on my side.

```
C:\Users\MarcinS\IdeaProjects\Beta2\WynikiZawodow\src\com>javac *.java
Exception in thread "main" java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char < * > at index 0: *.java
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.normalize(WindowsPathParser.java:182)
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:153)
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:77)
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsPath.parse(WindowsPath.java:92)
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystem.getPath(WindowsFileSystem.java:229)
        at java.base/java.nio.file.Paths.get(Paths.java:84)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main.Option$37.process(Option.java:700)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main.Option.handleOption(Option.java:1098)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main.Arguments.doProcessArgs(Arguments.java:401)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main.Arguments.processArgs(Arguments.java:367)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main.Arguments.init(Arguments.java:193)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:222)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:162)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.Main.compile(Main.java:57)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.Main.main(Main.java:43)
```

Comment: Are your classes in the default package?

Comment: While you project grows, don't you think migrating to a IDE and/or a build tool such Ant, Maven or Gradle?

Comment: they are in 3 different packages. 
I use InteliJ. but then again i found a tutorial for 12 screens on "how to compile your working *** project into .jar". And complexity of it annoys me so much that i chose the 'simpler' way of javac *.java, which should by all means work. As mentioned i know a work around, but i think it's at least interesting problem to solve (and the one that might bit me, or some else in the ass in the future)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you said in your answer to my question in the comments, your classes are in its own package. In order to compile this, your shell's current directory must be the directory where your packages (i.e. subdirectories) start. This has the effect that you start your compiler with no java files in it, so the shell can't resolve *.java into the list of java files in that directory, `*.java` will be passed to the Java compiler that in turn tries to make sense out of that filename.

It's not javac's fault because filename resolving is the shell's job. Since you already have a workaround in place you can continue using that or switch to an IDE which comes with additional features that will make your life easier (at least in termns of programming Java ;-)

Comment: well fun fact, due to InteliJ default way of creating packages, if i go to the level where i have at least one .java, i am below the level of my packages root (com/comapny/main, so if i go to company,  there are other packages there, but import statment will not work cause there is no com.company, as the com folder is higher). also if java has done anything ever, it's never easier than anything.